# How to zgrep by file pattern and timestamp?

Tags: linux, shell, grep, gzip

I have a list of several thousand gzip (`*.gz`) files that I'd like to `zgrep` through, but I only want to run it on files with a last-modified-timestamp on or after yesterday (11/22/2012) and that contain the string "widget" in their filnames (filtering by these reduces the number of files to about 80).

I don't see any timestamp or file pattern arguments that I can add to my `zgrep` command - any ideas?

For example:

```
eijdij8484.gz modified last on 11/20/2012 <== dont zgrep
dj8j4848ju-widget-dj8d4dj48d.gz modified last on 11/20/2012 <== dont zgrep bc of timestamp
ijdijdijdjii.gz modified last on 11/23/2012 <== dont zgrep bc no "widget" in filename
3ijdidj4-widget-jd9idj48.gz modified last on 11/22/2012 <== zgrep!
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might get you going the right direction.

```
#!/bin/bash
    cutoff="20121122"
    for i in `find . -type f -name "*widget*.gz"; do
        modDate="`stat -c %y $i | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/-//g'`"
        if [ ${modDate} < ${cutoff} ]; then
            command here on $i
        fi
    done
```

This was a quick write-up because my wife is waiting on me to get out of the house, so try that for a bit and I will try to test it out more in-depth later this evening.

**Edit** - Is this meant to be a floating "yesterday" relative to the current day?  Or is it a hard "11/22/12"?

Comment: Floating yesterday, but dont sweat it - i can tweak it from here, thanks!!

Comment: Awesome, hope it gets you where you want to be!

Comment: If you want it: `date --date='1 day ago' +%Y%m%d` does it.